# .htaccess tweak to redirect to /subfolder/public

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, redirect

I have this script running on all my Laravel sites deployed on shared hosting to prepend www and to redirect all traffic to /public.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

What I'd like to do now is to tweak it so it redirects the traffic to /subfolder/public, but I'm having troubles making it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/public/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subfolder/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I get an Internal Server Error

Comment: I don't get any error while using same rules on my Apache. Make sure these rules are in site root .htaccess and there is no other conflicting rule. Moreover check your Apache error log file for reason of 500 error

Comment: So I need to have my .htaccess in the root? There is a .htaccess file there already (that I haven't wrote) with these contents: http://pastebin.com/uDytQd7q (Is there a way to include code in comments?)

How can I combine the two?

Comment: I've tried so many combinations, using [L] flags, nothing seems to work. I am clueless. Care to help me further? Would be much appreciated

Comment: `RewriteBase /index.php` is definitely wrong in your htaccess. Besides you need to tell in which folder is this .htaccess located and is `subfolder/public/` a sub-directory of that location ?